# How to hide files in a website

Tags: php

I'm trying to hide my pdf files from users but I want them to be downloadable.
Heres my file structure

```
+-- index.php
+-- download.php
+-- content
    +-- .htaccess
    +-- files
       +-- pdf.pdf
       +-- pdf2.pdf
```

I tried to block users access to the content folder with `.htaccess`.

```
deny from all
```

But when i download pdf file with this

```
//download.php
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
$file = "http://localhost/content/files/pdf2.pdf";
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");
```

Browser can't load it.
I can't figure out another way to do this

Users can upload files to the site and decide a price for it.
And when you have paid for it you can download it. There will be mysql query before downloading to check if user have bought it

Comment: Which is it? Do you want people to have access to the files or don't you?

Comment: Your `download.php` file isn't actually doing anything. It is setting some headers, but doesn't return any content. You have to call `readfile('server/path/to/pdf2.pdf')` to output the contents of the file. In your case, you can do `readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/content/files/pdf2.pdf')`

Comment: Place a blank index.php file inside your files folder no one can see if not know the actual URL of the archive.

Comment: Don't put it in the htdocs and create a download page where you link to the files you want downloaded.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? Put `readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/content/files/pdf2.pdf');` at the bottom of your `download.php`. That should work.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I tried and it didn't affect anything.

Comment: hmm it should work. Maybe you have errors and they are being hidden from you. Put `ini_set('display_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top and check if any PHP errors show up.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the browser can't load it? Nothing shows up on the screen?

Comment: @KodosJohnson It opens the pdf window but display `error to load pdf content`

Comment: @KodosJohnson no errors

Comment: @KodosJohnson It worked when i moved the file to the same directory as `download.php` and edited the `$file` to `http://localhost/pdf2.pdf`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147499/discussion-between-toni-and-kodos-johnson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `download.php` file is just setting some headers to tell the browser to download the file. It doesn't actually write the content of the file in the response. You just have to add the following line of code to the end of `download.php`:

```
readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/content/files/pdf2.pdf");
```

NOTE: As gview mentioned in the comments, the proper way to do this would be to move the files outside the document root so they cannot be accessed regardless of your per-directory htaccess file. You can still use my solution, but instead of using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, you would put the server path. Like this:

```
readfile("/server/path/to/content/files/pdf2.pdf");
```

Comment: This is just not the way to do this.  Sure it works, but the better solution is to have the files outside of the web root, so that there is no way that they could be reached in webspace, with or without an apache rule that denies access.  It is also not a complete answer to the question. It seems like you simply helped debug a trivial issue, when the actual solution to the problem involves steps in the comments (add rules to a per directory .htaccess).

Comment: @gview Although I fully agree with you, it's not always possible. Perhaps it's shared hosting and OP simply doesn't have access to anything outside of the document root.

Comment: I have never seen that situation even with shared hosting.  Maybe under windows shared hosting, which I have never seen personally?  Usually there's some sort of file manager app that lets you make a directory and move files to it, often in concert with mod_userdir under apache.  With mod_userdir, they never map directly to a user's home directory which would be a huge security hole -- it's to a directory beneath home.

Comment: @gview The OP already had the rules in the htaccess file, the only problem was they didn't read and display the contents of the file. FWIW, I agree with you that they should put the files outside the document root, but that's not what was giving the OP their problem.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that per directory htaccess is slow, possibly circumventable and an administration hassle.  It's nothing personal, but in the future if people find this question, at least someone has articulated that this isn't the best way to solve the problem stated, even if the OP went down the wrong path from the get-go.